# How to calculate correctly in php?

Tags: php, math

```
$total = 30 - $nr1 / 13 - $nr2 - 6 * $nr3 - 3
```

I know we learned that in school but what is first (+ or - or * or /), where are the brackets or do I even need them ?

Comment: Unless this is homework, use brackets, so you don't need to remember precedence rules

Comment: Suggestion: take an algebra review class.  Seriously.

Comment: I realize the title says "php," but this is really a math question, not a programming question. (I suppose you could argue that some programming language could implement math in some unconventional way, like using the `+` symbol to mean division, but that's pretty far-fetched.)

Comment: 6 Letters.. PEMDAS. I suggest you Google it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You put brackets to priortizes what should be calculated ***first***. In math though it starts from division, multiplication, subtraction and finally addition. So, here is the order of precedence for these:

- division
- multiplication
- subtraction
- addition

You can however **override** that rule by specifying brackets, for example you might want to have addition calculated first before anything else.

**More Info:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: This isn't 100% correct is it? Algebra (and C like languages in general) parse left to right, with equal but higher precedence given to `[/|*]` and equal but lower precedence given to `[-|+]`, in respect to these four operators (where `[]` denotes some set of operators, and `|` denotes a separation of that sets elements, indicating only one can be chosen)

Answer (score 3):

```
$total = 30 - ($nr1 / 13) - $nr2 - (6 * $nr3) - 3
```

I don't think extra brackets would harm. I always use them to improve readability

Answer (score 2):

See the chapter about [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 1):

First partentheses are calculated. Then multiplication and division. Then plus and minus. If you write say a*b/c, because multiplication doesn't precede division, nor does division precede multiplication, the computer will calculate it in the order it stands. So it will first calculate a*b and then divide that by c.

Comment: @Matt Ellen - not in all cases... a*(b/c) can be zero in some cases where c>b is zero and so is a*0... IMO, it's always better to have (a*b)/c..

Answer (score 1):

```
division, multiplication, addition, subtraction (/, *, +, -)
```

Answer (score 1):

the +- and */ pairs are of equal precedence. they are evaluated left to right.